# Detecting changes in a global object using Proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

```
    const scopeHandler = {
        set: function(obj, prop, value) {
            console.log(`${prop} changed from ${obj[prop]} to ${value}`);
            obj[prop] = value;
            return true;
        }
    };
    const scopeProxy = new Proxy(window.app, scopeHandler);
```

So I'm trying to detect any changes whenever `app` or any of its children `app.reports` changes, but it doesn't log anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Proxy will only appear to do anything if the *Proxy itself* is the value that's "changed" later (via property assignment or whatever traps you have).

If you have an existing object, create a Proxy wrapper for it, and then other parts of an app use *the existing object*, you won't see anything happen with the Proxy; the other parts of the object would have to have *the Proxy* instead of the original object.

Here, you might be able to reassign `window.app` to the Proxy, so that other references to `window.app` now reference the Proxy instead.

```
window.app = new Proxy(window.app, scopeHandler);
```